# odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error while validating view:

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-12, odoo-14

1. List item

When I try to upgrade the module following error occurred and I attach the picture of the error.

2.How Can I resolve this error

```
  **Code:**    
   Action 226 (id: 226) does not exist for button of type action.

View name: project.project.new.form
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(1455,)
 xmlid: project_form_inherited_new
 view.model: project.project
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(627,)
 file: /opt/workspace/v10tov14convert/addons/timesheet_invoice_create/views/project_inherit.xml
 <record id="project_form_inherited_new" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">project.project.new.form</field>
            <field name="model">project.project</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <xpath expr="//notebook/page[2]/group[1]/group[2]/field[@name='analytic_account_id']" position="after">
                           <field name="employee_id" groups="timesheet_invoice_create.group_timesheet_employee"/>
                           <field name="timesheet_cost" groups="timesheet_invoice_create.group_timesheet_employee"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with different action code which appeared only if you try to inherit from the view, otherwise, form works fine. The root cause is the button  <button name="226" string=" ... in your XML. Either delete it or fix the action and error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the complete error log- the error image you have given is not showing proper reference.

Looks like you used some action_id on your action button which is missing from view or you forgot to identify the module name in before action_id
For Example

```
<button type='action' name='module_name.action_id' string="Example' class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [View resolution](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html#view-resolution) documentation:

> The parent is fully resolved, then the current view’s inheritance specs are applied.

The error happens when it tries to resolve the parent arch

One of the views inheriting from `project.edit_project` (or this view itself) has a button of type action that fail to validated. As the error message specify, the action with ID 226 does not [exist in database](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py#L1157).

We can reproduce the error by deleting the `portal.portal_share_action` which is used in `project.edit_project` view, then updating a module which inherit the base view.